# How can I filter the domains served by a CDN from a list of domain names?

Tags: python, cdn, detect

I have a list of domains and I need to filter the domains served by a CDN(Content Delivery Network). I am going to use python script to do that.
At the first I was thinking I can identify them from the domain name. But not all of the domain names have cdn keyword.

Is there any reason or any feature in the CDN served domains which I use that for identifying CDN served domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can't do it with 100% accuracy.

But you can identify domains using popular cloud providers in many cases by tracking CNAME records which would lead the respective provider's servers. 
I.e. here's a doc on Amazon CloudFront http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html

> In CloudFront, an alternate domain name, also known as a CNAME, lets
>   you use your own domain name (for example, www.example.com) for links
>   to your objects instead of using the domain name that CloudFront
>   assigns to your distribution

Example:

```
dig -t CNAME c.amazon-adsystem.com
c.amazon-adsystem.com.  896     IN      CNAME   d1ykf07e75w7ss.cloudfront.net.
```

Comment: But I can not use popular cloud providers. I mean, I am using python scripts and I wanna to handle this in my python codes. In your mentioned example, what if we do not have cloudfront.net in our result? Do all CDN served domains have clouldfront token in their CNAME?

Comment: If you need it in python just google how to work with DNS in python. Of course not all solutions of this kind rely on amazon cloudfront - you need to make up your own list of the providers you're going to track. And as I wrote you can't check it in general case - it can be a custom solution you know nothing of